# jQuery get url not fixed/static

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get some xml into a html table. The thing is my xml is created dynamically on the server as a temporary document. How can I call this file if the url can be different? I hope this makes sense. I am new to jQuery, Javascript.

Comment: Is it the url that's dynamic or the actual xml content being served from the server? I doubt there's anything you can do if the url is dynamic (which I find weird).

Answer (score 0):

At the time of dynamic generation of the file on the server, also write the path of the file in a static file. Use the client to retrieve the path from the static file and then make the actual request to the dynamically generated file.

hope i understood your question right.